# How to load NASA JPL WMS Global Mosaic into QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I was playing around with uDIG and realized that its WMS capabilities are awesome! The Global Mosaic perfectly fits a map I created! However, I was planning to use the WMS layer as an orientation for cleaning up my polygons, yet geoprocessing (merge etc.) is not very much straightforward in uDIG (is it?).

Therefore I wanted to load the WMS into QGIS (1.7.2). After I set up the connection as
http://wms.jpl.nasa.gov/wms.cgi?

the connection works but when loading any service I get the following response:

```
Antwort: <?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://wms.jpl.nasa.gov/exception_1_1_1.dtd ">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException>
This server no longer provides full WMS services!
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for correctly loading this WMS into QGIS?

Comment: "This server no longer provides full WMS services!" -> the service was discontinued by NASA. The server uDIG is using is probably another one, just copy the URL and use it to add a new connection in QGIS.

Comment: @Jens - Have you tried JPL's OnEarth WMS? This has the global mosaic layers. http://onearth.jpl.nasa.gov/wms.cgi?

Comment: Hi, when I add your suggest URL, then I still get this error:
 "Map request error (Status: 200; Response: <?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://wms.jpl.nasa.gov/exception_1_1_1.dtd ">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException>" 

Meaning, it still looks for http://wms.jpl.nasa.gov/...

Comment: http://onearth.jpl.nasa.gov/wms.cgi?request=GetTileService this is the WMTS endpoint.

Comment: http://onearth.jpl.nasa.gov/wms.cgi?request=GetMap&layers=global_mosaic&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image/jpeg&styles=&width=512&height=512&bbox=-180,-166,76,90request=GetMap&layers=global_mosaic&srs=EPSG:4326&width=512&height=512&bbox=-180,-166,76,90&format=image/jpeg&version=1.1.1&styles=request=GetMap&layers=global_mosaic&srs=EPSG:4326&width=512&height=512&bbox=-180,-166,76,90&format=image/jpeg&version=1.1.1&styles=defaultrequest=GetMap&layers=global_mosaic&srs=EPSG:4326&width=512&height=512&bbox=-180,-166,76,90&format=image/jpeg&styles=default   -- this a sample WMS request for image response.

Comment: http://onearth.jpl.nasa.gov/tiled.html  - this describes JPLs movement from WMS to a prototype GetTileRequest (WMS-T, WMTS) for the short term.  The links in my earlier comments above are from this page.

Comment: very interesting! I will try it out today once more. thx!

Answer (score 1):

JPL don't provide a WMS service any more (the clue is in the error message). I believe that what you have in UDig is some sort of tile service like WMTS or TMS.

[This thread](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Does-QGIS-Support-WMS-Tile-Service-td4105830.html) suggests that you need to use GDAL to load a TMS layer into QGis.